# React Native Flatlist with Typescript:Property 'data' is optional in type but required in type 'Readonly<FlatListProps<string>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Here's my FlatList:

```
  <FlatList
    {...omit(this.props, [
      "id",
      "loading",
    ])}
    nestedScrollEnabled
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
    ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
  />
```

Here's a renderItem:

```
  @autobind
  renderItem<
    I extends ILVITem,
    IX extends { toString: () => string }
  >({ item, index }: { item: I; index: IX }) {
    if (!isFunction(this.props.itemConfig)) {
      return null;
    }
    const itemConfig = this.props.itemConfig(item);
    if (isEmpty(itemConfig)) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <ListRow
        throwData={item}
        title={this.titleState(item, itemConfig)}
        subtitle={this.subtitleState(item, itemConfig)}
      />
    );
  }
```

My problem:

```
 Property 'data' is optional in type '{ nestedScrollEnabled: true; renderItem: <I extends ILVITem, IX extends { toString: () => string; }>({ item, index }: { item: I; index: IX; }) => Element | null; onEndReached: () => void; ListFooterComponent: () => Element | null; ... 15 more ...; onPress?: (() => any) | undefined; }' but required in type 'Readonly<FlatListProps<string>>'.
```

I don't see any reason of this error. Is there any way to make `data` not optional?

in `ILVITem` interface `data` is not optional.

Comment: On which line is this error occurring?

Comment: What's `this.props`? Also what is the definition for `omit`?

Comment: @catgirlkelly u mean the interface or what's exactly inside?

Comment: omit is `lodash` method

Comment: Yeah I would like the definition for `this.props`.

Comment: Can you post the `ILVITem` interface?

Comment: @catgirlkelly - thanks! I just have found out why I had this issue: Ian's answer helped with the issue

Answer (score 1):

Had almost the same issue. If you have `data` in `this.props` and use something like `spread operator`, `pick`, `omit` in `FlatList` props - TS won't "understand" that. You need to pass `data` prop in any case:

```
  <FlatList
    {...omit(this.props, [
      "id",
      "loading",
    ])}
    data={this.props.data}
    nestedScrollEnabled
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    onEndReached={this.onEndReached}
    ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
  />
```